# Integrability of first derivative

Tags: integration, continuity

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous. This means that $f$ is integrable on any closed interval $[a,b]$. Does this imply that $f'(x): \frac{df(x)}{dx}$ is integrable over any $[a,b]$ too?

Comment: Yes, it does (if $f'(x)$ exists for any $x$, which is a stronger requirement than simply being continuous).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because the derivative has to exist. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function for an example in which the derivative exists *nowhere*.

If the derivative exists then the answer is yes (it's the fundamental theorem of calculus basically), but this requirement is far more strict than "just" continuity.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand when you say "it's the fundamental theorem of calculus basically": $f$ is by definition the anti-derivative of $f'$. The fundamental theorem of calculus says that if $f'$ is integrable then we have some consequences about $f$. Hence, $f'$ integrable is a sufficient condition for the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to hold, I think. Am I wrong?

Comment: The fact that $f$ is absolutely continuous on any interval $[a,b]$ is enough to assume that.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 So, does the absolute continuity of $f$ imply integrability of $f'$? As OP says,  the fundamental theorem is statement about the value of the integral of the derivative, based on integrability of that derivative, but the interest here is on proving exactly that hypothesis, integrability of $f'$